# Canon PIXMA P200 cannot scan in Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: scanner, canon

Good day.
I just started using Ubuntu 16.04LTS and is testing everything.
My only concern for now is that I cannot use anymore the scanning capability of my Canon P200. I searched this forum but nothing was mentioned about P200. I searched Ubuntu Software but to no avail.
I hope someone could assist me, and hopefully using GUI's and much as possible not the Terminal.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I can't find this device listed on SANE;

If you install the scanner drivers that Canon supply;

go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100553101.html and click to download and save what will be scangearmp-p200series-2.20-1-deb.tar.gz

Open a terminal; 
copy each command below; paste into the terminal

```
cd Downloads

tar -zxvf scangearmp-p200series-2.20-1-deb.tar.gz

cd scangearmp-p200series-2.20-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

that installs the drivers and to test type or paste into the terminal

```
scangearmp
```

to run the programme; let us know how it goes

Comment: wow! works like a charm! what a very helpful community! everything is working as it should. By the way, one last assistance, could you teach me how to change the icon of the scangear in the launcher? I had it locked there but the icon is a just a big question mark with a grey square background. Again, thank you so so much!

Comment: have a look in /usr/share/Icons and hunt around there; to make your own, you save an image as .png and shrink it to 4kB and then point the launcher to that; (you did very well to set up a launcher)

Comment: pdc, sorry for the delayed response. Can you walk me through this " have a look in /usr/share/Icons " . Am I going to type this in the "terminal" ? or just search in the "dash" ? sorry, I am just a new user of Ubuntu. Just wondering, other software installed automatically has its own icon and I just locked it in the launcher. But this Scangear has no icon?

Comment: If you have an icon on your Desktop for your Home folder; it may have an option there to click on what is called File System; inside that are the various file system folders; including /usr so inside that /usr is a share folder, and inside that, /icons and some sub-folders too but you can see what the images are; and their size; I used a jpeg image for our scangear; shrunk its size in GIMP; to very small; saved as .png then pointed the launcher to find that image

Comment: @ pdc, thanks for the response. Will try it asap and revert to you for the results. What a nice community here! thanks

Comment: @ pdc, still Icant search for the scangear change icon in /usr/share/icons. anyway, I will still try and try, and hopefully will succeed later. thanks for the assistance. cheers!

Comment: @ pdc there is no option to "print to jpg" in the preference of Canon ScanGear. The only options are save to "PRINT" / "OCR" / "IMAGE-PNG". Is there any workaround? Or should I install another software? If yes, any specific software name? This is just a follow up question, but should I open a new question ticket?

Comment: there isn't a specific scangear icon: just use what the system gives you; or borrow one from another programme; I don't understand your "print to jpg" comment; we are misunderstanding each other; as long as you can get scangear to work!!

Comment: @ pdc, what I meant for print to jpg is that I cannot save my scanned documentas *.jpeg file. the only options for saving file is *.pdf and *.png. Is there any ubuntu software that I can install to convert png to pdf file?

Comment: I would use Gimp: I think it is called .. export as ..